# ApplicationListener<EurekaInstanceCanceledEvent> call total 4 time when service deregister form eureka server way is this?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

Registered instance API-GATEWAY-SERVICE/192.168.43.187:api-gateway-service:8090 with status DOWN (replication=true)
Cancelled instance API-GATEWAY-SERVICE/192.168.43.187:api-gateway-service:8090 (replication=false)

i want to konw way **onApplicationEvent** method of **ApplicationListener** listener call 4 time when client service deregister with  eureka server.